# QRegExpValidator maximum value

Tags: c++, regex, qt, validation, qregexp

I would like to use QRegExpValidator in order to force user to:
- type in values only from a certain range (double type),
- the double type should be typed in using dot not coma
- no other formats are allowed

So far I have:

```
QRegExpValidator* rxv = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"), this);
```

This validator forces user to type in only double values with dot. I Dont know however, how to prevent user from typing in values out of range (for example range would be from 0 to 100.0). I Would aprichiate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own validator, derived from `QValidator`. All you need is to implement `virtual State validate(QString &input, int &pos) const = 0`.

**UPDATE**

Example:

**MyValidator.h**:

```
class MyValidator : public QValidator
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyValidator(double min, double max, QObject *parent = 0);

    State validate(QString &input, int &pos) const;

private:
    QRegExp mRexp;
    double mMin;
    double mMax;
};
```

**MyValidator.cpp**:

```
MyValidator::MyValidator(double min, double max, QObject *parent) :
    QValidator(parent)
  , mRexp("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")
  , mMin(min)
  , mMax(max)
{}

QValidator::State MyValidator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
{
    if (input.isEmpty())
        return Acceptable;
    if (!mRexp.exactMatch(input))
        return Invalid;
    const double val = input.toDouble();
    if (mMin <= val && val <= mMax)
        return Acceptable;
    return Intermediate;
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to do that, would you mind showing some code example?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is nearly the one. I tried modyfing it a bot to work as it really should, but I havent succed. The problem lies in MyValidator method. For example, lets say min is 5 and max is 9. After I write in (to the lineEdit for example) number 1, I cannot backspace anymore, as it is threated as Invalid. On the other hand if I change the first expression to return Intermediate, I will be able to accept number 1... How to get over this?

Comment: Updated sources. Also, I would recommend you to change your regexp to this: "[-+]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?" - easier to input fractional numbers.

Comment: I think it does work now, but I can enter negative values now. EDIT: I think the regex doesnt work at all in this function

Comment: Of course, it works - it doesn't allow you to input letters and stuff. Also, it contains '-' simbol. If you do not want negative values - remove this from regexp. Or make the validation function more complex. Mine is just an example.